# Can't find how to install MySql on windows

Tags: windows-7, installation, mysql

**How can I install MySql on Windows?

I've tried several times and it fails**.

- ***My pc specs:***

  OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
  Version 6.1.7600 Build 7600
  Other OS Description    
  OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
  System Name BHALL-PC
  System Manufacturer Hewlett-Packard
  System Model    HP dx2280 MT(GN967PA)
  System Type X86-based PC
  Processor   Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 2.80GHz, 2793 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical
   Processor(s)
  BIOS Version/Date   Award Software International, Inc. V1.09, 3/16/2007
  SMBIOS Version  2.4
  Windows Directory   C:\Windows
  System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
  Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
  Locale  United States
  Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "6.1.7600.16385"
  User Name   BHALL-PC\BHALL
  Time Zone   India Standard Time
  Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 
  Total Physical Memory   1.99 GB
  Available Physical Memory   458 MB
  Total Virtual Memory    3.98 GB
  Available Virtual Memory    2.02 GB
  Page File Space 1.99 GB
  Page File   C:\pagefile.sys

Comment: **How does it fail?  What error?  What exactly did you download?**

Comment: I downloaded a zip file about 300 mbs and then unziped it. Installer is absent.

Comment: MySQL should only be downloaded from the official site. Just downloading any 300MB zip file will not get you MySQL.

Comment: @music2myear there are zip file downloads on the [official download page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.6.html).  They are almost never the correct thing to download though.  For windows you should almost always get the MSI.

Comment: I was commenting on the lack of precision and therefore the effective uselessness of the response OP made to your comment, but that is a good point too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit the [official download site](https://www.mysql.com/downloads/), download and install.

You most likely want the [community server](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).

Comment: Or better, download [MariaDB](https://downloads.mariadb.org/)

Comment: what is MaridaDB? @cylgalad

Comment: A fork of MySQL. It's supposed to be compatible but does implement some additional features/does some things differently. But should behave the same/similar to MySQL in most cases if an application uses a database.